# .gitignore to retain one file

Tags: git, jenkins, gitignore, git-add

I'm trying to create a cronjob to backup all my Jenkins configuration in git. The only thing I need to be tracked in my repository is the `config.xml` in every Jenkins project. The file system is structured like `../jenkins/jobs/[PROJECTNAME]/config.xml`. The `.git` is located in jobs.

I don't want to explicitly ignore all other folder/files, but allow only the `config.xml` in that location. I came up with the following working solution:

```
*

!.gitignore
!config.xml
!*/

*/workspace
*/modules
/config-history
*/config-history
*/*/config-history
*/*/*/config-history
*/*/*/*/config-history
*/*/*/*/*/config-history
*/*/*/*/*/*/config-history
*/*/*/*/*/*/*/config-history
```

Unfortunate there are many projects and the `git add .` takes a while. Ignore `workspace`, the directly with most files in, didn't add any benefit.

Btw. the intuitive and short way didn't work at all:

```
*
!.gitignore
!*/config.xml
```

Any ideas to either optimize my .gitignore or my git add without listing all files in either case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since this is but an automated task, why don't you just simply add only the files you need? Replace

```
git add .
```

with

```
git add config.xml
```

and git will not have to traverse the whole project tree.

If you want to show the status of your repo, without the load of untracked files, use

```
git status -uno
```

EDIT: Of course you have to be in the directory with the `config.xml` you want to add; if you want to add all `config.xml`s in your current directory's subdirectories, use

```
git add */config.xml
```

Comment: I quickly tried your approuch on a sample repo, but this is not working on subdirectories? There are added new projects at any time and of course I want to backup also new config.xml. Keep in mind that the configs are located in /[projectname]/config.xml in relation to git.

Comment: `git add <file>` is unambigous. The only reason that *you* need .gitignore is that, instead of adding the file you actually want to add, you add the whole directory containing the file. Thus: Are you still doing `git add .`? You really should not.

Comment: I don't get it. See my example: `>mkdir gittest
>cd gittest
\gittest>git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/User/gittest/.git/
\gittest>echo "xx" > config.xml
\gittest>mkdir sub
\gittest>cd sub
\gittest\sub>echo "xx2" > config.xml
\gittest\sub>echo "xx4" > other.xml
\gittest\sub>cd ..
\gittest>git add -n .
add 'config.xml'
add 'sub/config.xml'
add 'sub/other.xml'
\gittest>git add -n config.xml
add 'config.xml'` (Copy it somewhery to read it :))

Comment: This was for test purpose only. The second was the important. But now I have it: `>git add -n */config.xml`

Comment: Please update you anwser to really match my question. I excepted and upvoted it already, as it was the right direction.

Comment: It matches your question. I was presuming you understood the basic path logic of git :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could at least shorten your .gitignore by using the double-asterisk:

```
# other stuff here
**/config-history
```

It will match `config-history` in any path.

Comment: Thanks for the hind, but I can remember that I had trouble with this while experimenting. But I will retest this again.